# Car leasing too cheap

Tags: auto-leasing, poland

I've got an offer from car dealer to lease a new car for 24 months:

Lease offer (I haven't seen contract yet):

- operational lease
- first payment 45%
- principal-interest 1.59% (for 24 month)
- buying out a car at the end 19%
- they say it's up to me where I'll insure the car
- total cost of the leasing (including buy out) **102.24%**

However the loan for the same car with high first payment will cost 10%. They say that they have special black week deal for leasing.

I'm wondering is it possible to have only 2.24% cost in case of leasing or where the hidden payments could be?

Comment: That doesn't look like a lease, more like an installment sale

Comment: Inflated base price. I don't see any info regarding the price tag of the vehicle relative to market prices (aka blue book).

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with European leases - is the "first payment" 45% of the base price? And is the buy-out 19% of that same base price? If so that does not look cheap to me. And I'm guessing that the total  cost is actually 102.24%, not 2.24%.

Comment: I still havent saw a contract yet. 
first payment = 45%
interest rate = 1.59% X 24 month (not principal - my mistake)
possibility to buy-out = 19%
when we sum up 45% + 1.59% x 24 + 19% = 102.24%
after I'll buy-out the car will be on my name.
But it's too cheap, doesn't it? or is there hidden payments
I understood it as I'll lease operational (rent) a car for 24 month and will pay 45% + 1.59% x 24 and after that I can buy out it for only 19%